# how to bold text in whatsapp chat

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

Is there a way to apply bold formatting to text within WhatsApp chats on Android devices? I'm curious if such functionality is available for emphasizing text. If it's possible, it could enhance communication and expression within the app.

Answer (score 2):

You can bold your text by putting an asterisk before and after your text as described [here](https://faq.whatsapp.com/539178204879377/?cms_platform=android&helpref=platform_switcher):

> Bold
> To bold your message, place an asterisk on both sides of the text:
> *text*

For italic, you put an underscore before and after the text. It's basically using markdown.

Depending on the keyboard you use, you can alson select the text, then select Bold (you might have to select the 3-dot, then select Bold).